# Migrate Centos7 to new server

Tags: centos, nginx, migration, centos7

I have a Centos7 server running a setup of nginx/dovecot/ispconfig/roundcube/mariadb etc.. and a few other smaller things (as per https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-7-x86_64-nginx-dovecot-ispconfig-3). My nginx setup is not installed in the typical directory that a 'yum' install would use, so this bit worries me the most.

I am looking to move my server from once company to another (to move to a UK provider), but do not want to have to set it all up again as it will take me ages.

I've seen a few ideas like using rsync and things, but is there a better suggested way of doing this or a guide out there anyone has used before?

My concern comes to Users on the systems, and then system files like the eth0 config which obviously I don't want it holding the wrong IP on the new server etc.

Thanks!

Comment: This is why we get paid the big bucks. For your future system builds, look into configuration management systems such as ansible, salt, chef, puppet...

Answer (score 1):

This is why you should standardise servers rather than craft them.  If the process was well documented and you know what files need copying then it shouldn't take ages to set up again.

Even if you restore a backup to the new server you are still going to need to track down everywhere IP addresses are specified.  That won't be just eth0 it'll be where any of your services are bound to ip+port,iptables,db access rules, etc.